# Android - Java - Access private variable in Main-Activity from another instanced class

Tags: java, android

I've been thinking for hours about this problem now without finding a solution. Still I think I'm just overlooking some very simple things.

My program is (mainly) supposed to record and playback audio, so I got one Main-Activity which contains all the functions with interactivity to the user and I got one class I called 'AudioHandler' to manage all the audio stuff in the background.
The Main-Activity uses an instance of AudioHandler.

Within the AudioHandler-class I got an OnCompletionListener, to notice when playback of the recorded audio-file has finished.

The problem is: When playback has finished - and the OnCompletionListener gets called, I want to change an ImageView (Turn the pause-button into a play-button) in the Main-Activity.

**How can I access the ImageView in the Main-Activity from the AudioHandler-Instance?**

...without making the ImageView-Variable public.

*Method that calls play from the AudioHandler in the Main-Activity:*

```
  public State playRecording() {
    //change play-button to stop-button
    iPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop_button_active);

    //start or resume playback of the recorded Audio
    ah.play();

    //Return that the program is in playing-mode
    return State.PLAYING;
}
```

*play-function in AudioHandler*

```
  public void play() {
        try {

            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d("MEDIA_PLAYER", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("MEDIA_PLAYER", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        //add listener to notice when the end of the audio record has been reached 
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                //should somehow change the ImageView 'iPlay' in the Main-Activity when reaching this point.



            }
        });     
    }
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Marco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to gain access to a variable, that variable should be either package-accessible or public. Or, even better, you should have an encapsulating method. Something like:

```
// On the main class:
public ImageView getIPlay(){
    return iPlay;
}
private static MainActivity instance;
public MainActivity getInstance(){
    return instance;
}

/** Either on the constructor or the 'OnCreate' method, you should add: */
    instance = this;
```

Now you can access the ImageView from any Activity or class with:

```
   MainActivity.getInstance().getIPlay();
```

It's that simple, really. You can go through a lot of other solutions, from using reflection through AOP or any kind of things. But it's just making the issue more complex. Try creating the setter method.

Comment: But how do I access the getters and setter from another class without having an actual instance of the main-activity?

Comment: You can create the Main Activity as something like a Singleton. Let me edit my Answer.

Comment: public static MainActivity getInstance(){
  return instance;
  }

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about object encapsulation.

When you define an instance variable as private, you are saying that only that object and members of that class can access the variable.  This is a good thing because it protects you from accidentally changing data you did not want to.  This is also why we have getters and setters.

So in your class you have something I imagine looks like this

```
    public class Main {
... some code here
    private ImageView myView;
... more code here
```

what you need to do is add the following methods to your Main class

```
public ImageView getView() {
       return myView;
}
```

and

```
public void setView(ImageView a) {
       myView = a;
}
```

so now when you want to access the ImageView from another class, you just call something like Main.getView() and you'll have it.

Now if this doesn't answer your question, it's because you didn't design your app too thoughtfully (so it seems) but luckily I won't be the kind of responder who tells you to uproot everything you have done and start over.

It sounds like you're working with an Android app and your issue is to communicate between activities.

This is why Android has something called Intents.  You can send an Intent from one activity to another to carry data.  So in this case you would send an Intent from one activity to the main class that would tell the main class to change the picture in the imageview.  I won't lie, I suck at using intents but there are many wonderful tutorials online that will show you how to do this.

Another option would be to create a RemoteView of your layout that has the play/pause button and access it from the other activity, RemoteView has a built in function to change the bitmap of a remote imageview (again, see the Android Developer Documentation for RemoteView for more on this)

I'm sorry I couldn't give you some actual code, I'm not confident enough in my abilities on these topics but I'm 100% confident that one of the three methods I just listed will answer your question.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation. I just don't see how I could access the getters and setters from another class, as an instance from the main-activity doesn't exist (does it?). I guess you're right about the intents, I really need to understand them thoroughly. All the tutorials I found only explained how to switch between activities using intents.

Comment: So I don't know the structure of your application, but I think you're saying that Main is not a class from which you are creating many Main objects like Main1 and Main2 but rather a class that only exists to run itself, in which case the ImageView would not be an instance variable but a variable of the entire class.  In this case, declare the getter and setter as static methods so you can access them with Main.getView() or whatever just like you'd access a standard library function like Math.max() or something like that.  In this case you should also include everything you (see next comment)

Comment: ... instantiate the ImageView in the GetView method (such as getting the R.id.yourlayout file and using the GetViewbyID method to get the ImageView)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a public wrapper method within your main Activity that toggles the ImageView between Pause and Play.

Or, you could pass the the ImageView to the AudioHandler (via the constructor?) and just manipulate it there.

Comment: Passing the ImageView via the constructor works. I still get an error during runtime, but at least it compiles without error. Guess this is another bug I haven't found.

Comment: The wrapper class won't work, because I can't access the functions of the Main-Activity from another class - because it has no instance. Is there a way to do that I don't know about? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could technically pass "this" as a parameter in the Constructor.  Then you could call the toggle function off of that instance of the Activity.